# How to fix Kotlin REPL exception NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: exception, kotlin, read-eval-print-loop

I'm attempting to run the Kotlin REPL on my windows 10 machine, from the command line. I am receiving a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jline/reader/LineReaderBuilder` exception when running the command `kotlinc`

I have IntelliJ Ultimate 2019.1.3 installed, with the Kotlin plugin. I have the Kotlin standalone compiler also installed and I've added that location to my system path. I've tried to run the command from the standalone directory: "C:/Tools/kotlinc/bin" but no difference.

- OS Name: Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise
- Version  10.0.16299 Build 16299
- Kotlin version 1.3.40-release-123 (JRE 1.8.0_131-b11)
- java version "1.8.0_131"

I expect the REPL to start without an exception. What could be causing the exception?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like that was [a bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-32085) and [it has been fixed](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/releases/tag/v1.3.41) with Kotlin plugin & `kotlinc` version 1.3.41 (released today).